# Test for statistically significant difference between two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have two 2-D arrays with the same shape (105,234) named A & B essentially comprised of mean values from other arrays.  I am familiar with Python's scipy package, but I can't seem to find a way to test whether or not the two arrays are statistically significantly different at each individual array index.  I'm thinking this is just a large 2D paired T-test, but am having difficulty. Any ideas or other packages to use?

Comment: By "each individual array index", you mean whether each row is different? Also, could you provide a reproducible example of the kind of data you're working with?

Comment: To do a T-test you are going to need the variances of the populations from which you have calculated the means. How do you plan on getting those?  Alternatively, provide an example of your original data and how you process it before getting to the point of your question, and we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: No, I actually need to test each individual grid point against another gridpoint in a different array.

Comment: So, essentially two very large two dimensional arrays.  Testing whether or not they are statistically significantly different from one another at each individual location.

Comment: FWIW, I think this is pretty easy to do in MATLAB with ttest2.  I can't find anything in Python that has similar arguments.  SciPy's ttest_ind only outputs a 1 dimensional array.

Comment: The SciPy function equivalent to Matlab's `ttest2` is `scipy.stats.ttest_ind`. But neither of them is checking if the arrays are "statistically significantly different at each individual array index." What they do is compare the arrays column to column (for Matlab, rows in default SciPy). If you don't understand that statistical significance cannot be figured out from just two means, I'd suggest using the `random` module to generate your test results: at least you won't have the illusion of certainty...

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the underlying variance for each mean at the gridpoints is the same, and the number of observations is the same or is known, then we can use the arrays of means to estimate the standard deviation of the means directly.

Dividing the difference between gridpoints by the standard deviation, then gives t distributed random variables, that can be directly tested, i.e. the p-value can be calculated.

As tests for many points, we will run into a multiple testing problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons#Large-scale_multiple_testing and the p-values should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "Do two-dimensional distributions differ ?", see
[Numerical Recipes p. 763](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=763)
(and ask further on how to do that in numpy / scipy). 
You might also ask on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=compare+distributions).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that x,y coordinates do not matter and we just have the two huge sets of independent measurements.

One of the possible approaches could be just to compute standard deviation of mean for each array, multiply this value to the Student coefficient (probably somewhat 1.645 for your astronomic number of samples and 95 % confidence level) and obtain the confidence ranges around the mean this way. If the confidence ranges of the two different arrays overlap, the difference between them is not significant. Formulas can be found [here](http://ultrastudio.org/en/Confidence_interval).

Comment: Yes, the coordinates do matter.  I essentially have two very large two dimensional arrays. I need to test whether or not they are statistically significantly different from one another at each individual location in the array (e.g., is array1[33,133] different from array2[33,133]. Do this for the entire array and output a new 2D array (I'm guessing p or t values).

Comment: My answer is about how to compare the two arrays if they are different. Here seems more tricky. From having no better idea, maybe we could pick random say 50x50 sections, these could have confidence intervals around average and could be compared, if they differ significantly or not. Otherwise one cell in one array and another in another array seem not providing enough data for statistics I describe.

Answer (score -2):

Go to MS Excel.  If you don't have it your work does, there are alternatives

Enter the array of numbers in Excel worksheet.  Run the formula in the entry field, =TTEST (array1,array2,tail).  One tail is one, Two tail is two...easy peasy.  It's a simple Student's T and I believe you may still need a t-table to interpret the statistic (internet).  Yet it's quick for on the fly comparison of samples.